# Very simple assembly register comparison

Tags: assembly, x86

Hopefully what I'm asking makes sense. I am running a gdb debugger on some assembly code. I came across a line that has

```
cmp %eax, (%ebx)
```

Now, is there a difference when comparing these two registers, since one has parenthesis around it? The book I have does not do a great job of explaining this.

Comment: What book are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one with parenthesis means the value in the memory address pointed to by the register `%ebx`. The one without parenthesis means the value in the register itself.

Answer (score 2):

Assemblers for particular instructions sets come many flavors, often with different syntax.  You didn't tell us which assembler, so we are forced to guess.

My guess is that

```
 (<reg>)
```

means "use the register as a pointer into memory for the second operand."   There should be other variations corresponding to what is probably the x86 instruction set (again, you didn't tell us) allowing for offset and base + offset indexing, since those are very common addressing modes for the x86.

Comment: Sorry, I should've specified. It's in x86. Thank you for the timely and concise response!